# on which bases i can select good theme for joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I am new to Joomla. i have to select one theme from these two themes.

1. Rocket theme - http://demo.rockettheme.com/?template=acacia
2. Nemo White Premium Joomla Template - http://themeforest.net/item/nemo-white-premium-joomla-template/5507845?WT.ac=category_item&WT.seg_1=category_item&WT.z_author=ThemeRox

but exactly i don't know which parameters i have to consider for selecting theme like Framework.

I am not sure how to check which theme takes lesser load times amongst other things

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the templates you are considering are responsive and seem to be quite versatile.

You can check page load times using http://gtmetrix.com or http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt or similar. To make the test fair, you would need to install the templates on the same website and test the same content.

The RocketTheme framework is certainly feature rich but this doesn't necessarily seem to translate to long page load times.

For example, a quick check using http://gtmetrix.com shows http://demo.rockettheme.com/joomla/acacia loading 788KB in 2.29 seconds and http://themerox.com/themeforest/nemo loading 1.36MB in 3.76 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think anything takes longer than Rocketheme templates. As much as I love their designs, their Gantry framework is extremely heavy and will take a long time to load.

I've never used the Helix framework (even though it looks very promising), but in the end, the choice is entirely up to you. You would be better off simply going through each page on the demo sites to see which template suits your needs. Both templates are powered by popular frameworks so your are definitely guaranteed flexibility.

Comment: My site is http://www.guru99.com/. you can check that my website is for educational purpose. so theme should be light so its load time is less.

Comment: @Lodder, I'd be interested to know if you have seen any objective test results showing Gantry is heavier than other frameworks.

Comment: @NeilRobertson - I have done testing of my own using a couple of frameworks. The T3 Framework is also another very heavy framework. Don't get me wrong, these popular ones are all well optimized, however I deem Gantry and T3 extremely heavy due to the size of them. Zipped up, Gantry is 1.4MB, T3 is 1.89MB, Helix is 0.58MB, Warp is 0.38MB, so you can imagine the load speed of template that make full use of the heavy frameworks, especially on mobiles.

Comment: Hi @Lodder, this reply is a bit tardy but I built copies of the same website using Gantry 4, Gantry 5, Helix 3, YJSG and YT Framework last year and did some speed tests using GTMetrix. They all loaded in very similar time frames (about 2.2. seconds). The size of the installation package isn't necessarily an indication of how fast a website using that framework will load as much of this is the back-end administration etc.

Answer (score 2):

Beyond any requirements you may have for design, compatibility, etc, on your development website, use the default protostar template and start loading all the extensions you think you'll need for your project to make a draft of the final version and some sample content.

After that, try out the free or the demo templates from the several template builders and make them run with your project draft. At this point, the time you spend in the below phases, will save you time later on your project successful life and will ensure at leat a medium degree of security, compatibility and usability.

Simple steps for a wise selection:

a) check that the selected ones, for testing, are compatible with your Joomla! version. Also, if you're looking to use, let's say Bootstrap, make sure they do load Joomla's bootstrap and not their own version of customized Bootstrap (this will avoid you issues with layout).

b) check the loading time for each - Chrome Dev Tools is a great help on this task;

c) check their dependencies that might become costly in download times (some templates have huge dependencies on third-party or own scripts);

d) perform a sample check on some of the scripts (especially JavaScript) and see if they are conforming with standards (you can make them pass JSLint for example). This will give you some degree of security;

e) check that the extensions - built-in and third-party that you drafted, all work perfectly or at least with minor issues,

f) then go for the design appeal and with the previous tests passed, you've probably narrowed the selection to a couple;

As @Lodder mentioned, there are several templates that do have a lot of appeal but are extremely heavy, which turns out to be a big disadvantage in a time where velocity and performance are crucial for good performance and user experience.

Have fun with the process ;)

Comment: My site is http://www.guru99.com/. you can check that my website is for educational purpose. so theme should be light so its load time is less.